# What would the closed form expression of the summation of $k \times k!$ from $k=0$ to $n$ be?

Tags: combinatorics

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\ k! = {} ?$$
My teacher assigned this for homework, and I’ve been trying to figure this out, but I couldn’t think of any convenient generating functions or binomial terms or anything. Any hints or guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please know that this isn’t a do-my-homework site, and as such you need to show what you have done, and all the steps you have taken to attempt to solve this problem. For more information, please look to here:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 4):

Well, $k\cdot k!=(k+1-1)\cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!$, so it is just a telescoping sum. The sum will be $(n+1)!-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$k \cdot k!=(k+1-1) \cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!$

Now do telescopic summation.